# Compiler creates linkern, edgegen, fmatch but does not create concorde

Tags: c, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to compile Concorde with little to no prior knowledge about C. I have made some progress but the README file states the following:

---

configure determines many features about your operating system and
configuration which it uses to control concorde's compilation.  After
configure has run, you should look through the file INCLUDE/config.h
to make sure it has made reasonable choices.  Then, you can compile
concorde by using make:

```
$ make
```

This builds the concorde library (concorde.a), header file (concorde.h),
and several executable programs, including:

```
TSP/concorde      the TSP solver
LINKERN/linkern   the Lin-Kernighan TSP heuristic
EDGEGEN/edgegen   generates edge sets
FMATCH/fmatch     solves fractional 2-matching problems
```

NOTE that to build the concorde TSP solver (for the exact solution of
TSPs), you must specify an LP solver in the configure step (either
QSopt for CPLEX).

A short help menu for each of the executable codes can be obtained by
executing the code without any option, for example "concorde".  A
typical way to run the concorde solver is to use:  "concorde myprob.tsp"
where myprob.tsp is a TSP instance in TSPLIB format.  To test the
concorde solver run "concorde -s 99 -k 100" (this should generate and
solve a random geometric TSP on 100 points).

---

make command successfully created linkern, edgegen and fmatch without bothering but it could not created concorde. At first, it was giving some errors regarding the QSopt but I managed to solve them by downloading source files but right now it gives
**signal.c:204: more undefined references to `CCutil_signal_handler' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:58: concorde] Error 1**
CCutil_signal_handler is defined within signal.c and all files are being compiled as the MakeFile is as follows

```
SRCROOT = .
BLDROOT = .
CCINCDIR=$(SRCROOT)/INCLUDE
BLDINCDIR=$(BLDROOT)/INCLUDE

srcdir = .

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -O2  -I$(BLDROOT)/INCLUDE -I$(CCINCDIR)
LDFLAGS = -g -O2 
LIBFLAGS = -lm 
RANLIB = ranlib

OBJ_SUFFIX = o
o = $(OBJ_SUFFIX)

DIRS=BIGGUY   LOCALCUT COMBS    CUT      EDGEGEN  FMATCH   \
     HELDKARP KDTREE   LINKERN  LP       PQ       TINY     TOOLS    \
     TSP      UTIL     VERIFY

all: concorde.h concorde.a
    for i in $(DIRS); do ( cd $$i; $(MAKE) $@ ); done

everything: all
    for i in $(DIRS); do ( cd $$i; $(MAKE) $@ ); done

.PHONY: concorde.a
concorde.a:
    for i in $(DIRS); do ( cd $$i; $(MAKE) concorde.a ); done

INC_LIST=$(BLDINCDIR)/config.h  $(CCINCDIR)/machdefs.h $(CCINCDIR)/util.h     \
         $(CCINCDIR)/bigguy.h   $(CCINCDIR)/combs.h    $(CCINCDIR)/cut.h      \
         $(CCINCDIR)/delaunay.h $(CCINCDIR)/edgegen.h  $(CCINCDIR)/fmatch.h   \
         $(CCINCDIR)/heldkarp.h $(CCINCDIR)/kdtree.h   $(CCINCDIR)/linkern.h  \
         $(CCINCDIR)/lp.h       $(CCINCDIR)/tsp.h      $(CCINCDIR)/consec1.h  \
         $(CCINCDIR)/localcut.h $(CCINCDIR)/macrorus.h $(CCINCDIR)/mlinkern.h \
         $(CCINCDIR)/necklace.h $(CCINCDIR)/pqsets.h   $(CCINCDIR)/pq.h       \
         $(CCINCDIR)/cuttree.h                                                \
         $(CCINCDIR)/tinytsp.h  $(CCINCDIR)/tsp.h      $(CCINCDIR)/verify.h

concorde.h: $(INC_LIST) Makefile
    cat $(INC_LIST) | grep -v '#include "' > concorde.h

clean:
    -rm -f *.$o concorde.h concorde.a
    for i in $(DIRS); do ( cd $$i; $(MAKE) clean ); done

distclean: clean
    -rm -f Makefile */Makefile INCLUDE/config.h INCLUDE/Makefile.common \
               config.log config.cache config.status

depend.in:
    for i in $(DIRS); do (cd $$i; $(MAKE) depend.in); done
```